# How to deal with exponential call hierarchy in Microservices Architecture?

Tags: rest, architecture, microservices, distributed-computing, resiliency

I have the following call hierarchy in my architecture:

> **BFF → Microservice A → Microservice B → Anticorruption Layer → Legacy System**

In each service above I am using the [retry pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/patterns/retry) to deal with HTTP resiliency while one service request a resource in another service.

The problem becomes when, if I have a default policy of 3 retries for each request, this becomes exponential. For example, if my AntiCorruptionLayer is down and returning a 504 (Gateway timeout) and my BFF receives one request, it will retry for 3 times, while service A will retry for 9 times and B for 27 times for just one request!

How to deal with this problem? Any tips?

Comment: I don't understand. Retires only happen when the request fails. That means services down the chain do not make any requests at all.

Comment: @yurikilochek No. Given the scenario above, if my AnticorriptionLayer is down and returning, for example, a 504 Gateway Timeout, the call hierarchy will occur in a exponential way. All services have a retry policy of 3 times for failed requests, so if my BFF receives one request, it will retry 3 times, but A will retry 9 and B will retry 27 times.
Maybe should I use a circuit breaker too?

Comment: There is only one active chain in this tree of requests at any time, so I fail to see the problem. For BFF to report that a downstream service is down? You can just put a timeout on each request.